# Write a function that returns the coefficient of x^n

Tags: polynomials

Write a function `C[p_, x_, n_]` that returns the coefficient of $x^n$ in the polynomial equation.

```
C[p_, x_, n_] := ...
```

If we call `C[7 x^2 - 3 x^3, x, 2]`, the output should be 7. I don't want to use the `Coefficient[]` function in *Mathematica*, I just want to understand how it is done.

Comment: Is this a programming exercise from school, or something you're just wondering about?

Comment: Nothing, actually, I'm practising by solving exercises but on this one, i'm just completely stuck. From school, it's not a homework, it is in our book

Comment: Perhaps start by taking a look at the `FullForm` of a polynomial in *Mathematica*. You could then try your hand at some pattern matching using `Cases`...

Comment: Is it acceptable to differentiate $n-1$ times and then evaluate the polynomial at $0$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do what `SeriesCoefficient` does yourself

```
coeff[polynomial_, variable_, order_] := 
 D[polynomial, {variable, order}]/(order!) /. variable -> 0

coeff[7 x^2 - 3 x^3, x, 2]
(* 7 *)

coeff[347 x^19 - 7 x^2 - 3 x^3, x, 19]
(* 347 *)
```

Comment: If one wanted to be cruel, he could have posted a contour integral method for extracting the coefficient… and then there's the method that uses FFT.

Comment: There should be a badge or something for the most convoluted answer to a question.  Or the most inscrutable - some of the answers here are so compact I have no clue what they are doing

Comment: @JasonB I suppose one could propose it as a Mathematica-specific popularity contest on [codegolf.SE]

Comment: How about a prize for answers as short as a *Tweet*?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pattern-matching version (not tested carefully since the question is already answered):

```
coeff[poly_, var_, orders_List] := Cases[Expand@poly, a_. var^# :> a] & /@ orders
```

Usage: `orders` is a list of the wanted orders, so

```
poly = (x + 5) (x - 1) (x^2 + y); Expand@poly
coeff[poly, x, {3, 1, 8, 4}]
(* -5 x^2 + 4 x^3 + x^4 - 5 y + 4 x y + x^2 y *)
(* {{4}, {4 y}, {}, {1}} *)
```